# blank page after submitting a comment

Tags: comments, comment-form

I was testing a new website with Chrome (latest build), everything working fine (no new plugin installed during the test) when suddendly when I try to post a comment, after pressing the "reply" button it stops on a blank wp-comments-post.php without posting.

I am testing on localhost with MAMP.
The funny thing is on the other browsers installed in the same machine (Safari, FF) it is working regularly.

I have tried to overwrite the file from a wordrpess install, clear the cache, reboot, reboot MAMP, but nothing. I also checked the file wp-comments-post.php in the root and it is not blank and Akismet is disabled.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. It was an unclosed div.
Lesson learned: first validate your code completely, then ask for help ;)